# Sub routes inside the vue3 + vite micro frontend

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vite, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I am using vue3 + vite and a plugin

```
@originjs/vite-plugin-federation
```

to build a micro frontend. One app will be the host and one will be the remote, both will have their own routing. Is there a way to navigate remote app inside the host app.

If I export a single component from the remote app it is working, but if I export App.js with routing it is not working, can anybody provide general guidelines to this problem.

vite config of remote:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vueJsx from "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
const dependencies = require("./package.json").dependencies;

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
    federation({
      name: "remote-app",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./Test": "./src/App.vue",
      },
      shared: [{ ...dependencies }, "vue", "vue-router"],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

vite.config of host:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vueJsx from "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(),
    federation({
      name: "host-app",
      remotes: {
        remote: "http://127.0.0.1:5173/dist/assets/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: ["vue"],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been through this road recently and here are my findings:

It seems like `vite-plugin-federation` is not ready to handle two instances of vue-router. You can check the following links:

- [Remote app with vue-router in host app [Nested Routes] · Issue #282 · originjs/vite-plugin-federation](https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation/issues/282)
- [Discussions · originjs/vite-plugin-federation](https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation/discussions/195)

To summarize:

- The first solution exposed is to have all your routing in the host application, so you would have only one instance of the router in the host, then your remotes apps won't be real apps but a set of components
- Another solution (not really different from the first one) is to have the routes inside of your remote apps and expose them through the plugin, then merge them into the routes of your main router (in the host app)
- Another solution is to use [single-spa](https://single-spa.js.org/) to handle nested routing
- Last solution (IMHO) would be to use another router and expose its instance to the remote apps, I would look on the side of [TanStack Router](https://tanstack.com/router/v1) if I were you.

Conclusion:
Module Federation is not mature enough to handle nested routing correctly (for Vue, with React Router you can do it easily). And vue-router should be improved to be able to attach one instance of the router to multiple Vue apps.

Good luck with your search, and do not hesitate to keep people informed here if you find something useful.